# How can I hide unused node sockets?

Tags: node-editor

Is there a way to hide output node sockets that have nothing plugged into them?

This would be really useful, for instance when I am using the light path (or any other input node) and I am only using one output and the other 9 are just wasting space.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a way to do this (I think I have seen people on this site doing it).  But I can't remember how and I figure some other people may benefit from this if I ask the question here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Or even more effectively with plain ol H.

Comment: @VinceScalia Indeed, however with H you lose the labels of the sockets.

Comment: Also just plain H does not hide the actual sockets as the OP asked.

Comment: It shrinks *way* small though.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  @VinceScalia Only if it doesn't have many sockets, with the input nodes, H doesn't make it much smaller.

Comment: See edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be accomplished with some simple Python code.

```
bpy.types.NodeSocket([bpy_struct])
```

Use the **Hide** attribute, which has a value of false by default.

Visit the full documentation [**here**](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.NodeSocket.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I am pretty sure I saw someone (I think it was @Gandalf3) mention in a comment somewhere a way to do it without scripting.

Comment: I haven't been able to uncover that, if I do I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>H</kbd> will turn any node into a capsule. This is perfect if you don't plan on editing the particular node any more. From there you can grab the two little strikes in the right side of the capsule and shrink it more!

Just don't lose it's name!

[image]

You can even condense large nodes like light path, just make sure something is connected.
Shrink the large node with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> > <kbd>H</kbd> and then click the little arrow in the top left or press <kbd>H</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: You can also click the arrow at the top left of the node to do this.  But the problem is this doesn't hide unused sockets.  If you shrink a light path node it doesn't get much smaller since it still has to show all 10 sockets.

Comment: @PGmath see the edit.