# How do I put a stencil-like texture across a sectioned object PART II

Tags: modeling, uv, objects

Because this 3rd answer is very good I am creating a Part II post so as not to confuse this answer with the previous two answers as found here in the first post: [How do I put a stencil-like texture across a sectioned object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45638/how-do-i-put-a-stencil-like-texture-across-a-sectioned-object/45639)

To recap: I have an object I am trying to add a secondary graphic across sectioned planks of wood. In other words, (and not outlined in the first Question) is that there is also a wood texture on the crate that the text UVmap has to go OVER. Doubling the images.

Unlike the previous 2 answers this essentially maps two images to the side of the crate.

[image]