# How to prevent texture from tiling? (inb4 using mapping node)

Tags: texturing, vector-mapping, tilesize

How to prevent texture from repeating across the object surface in cycles?
Mapping node doesn't seems to work in this case.
[image: this is how min/max parameters working]

Comment: Are you using UV mapping there? When I do, then I project just the desired faces to map for the texture, and then the rest of the faces I shrink down into the spaces in the zero alpha range of the mapped image.

Comment: you could try a "decal" technique using an empty, something like this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45638/how-do-i-put-a-stencil-like-texture-across-a-sectioned-object/45645#45645, or UV mapping instead.