# Adding decals to aeroplane model

Tags: texturing

So this is the problem. Ive been tring to put the red dot on the 3d model, but i cannot seems to understand how texturing works, I already have a texture for my plane, but i want to put a png on that texture.[image: te]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/setup-a-decal-material-in-cycles  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45638/how-do-i-put-a-stencil-like-texture-across-a-sectioned-object