# How to hide unused Node socket using python script

Tags: python, scripting, materials, node-editor

I can manually hide unused node sockets by pressing Ctrl  H, but I wanted to know how to hide an unused node socket using a script I saw a previously asked question about this topic - [How can I hide unused node sockets?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22967/how-can-i-hide-unused-node-sockets) 
in the answers, [VRm](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/6204/vrm) answered that **Hide** attribute can do this but hide attribute can just collapse the node itself like when we press 'H.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either call [hide.socket_toggle()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.node.html?highlight=hide_socket_toggle#bpy.ops.node.hide_socket_toggle) operator on all nodes in selection or hide each socket one by one using [NodeSocket.hide](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeSocket.html?highlight=hide#bpy.types.NodeSocket.hide) property. Following demo is based on *Operator Node* template:

```
import bpy

def main(operator, context):
    node_selected = context.selected_nodes

    if node_selected:
        bpy.ops.node.hide_socket_toggle()
    else:
        operator.report({'ERROR'}, "Nothing selected")
        return

class NODE_OT_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "node.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Hide Node Sockets Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        space = context.space_data
        return space.type == 'NODE_EDITOR'

    def execute(self, context):
        main(self, context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NODE_OT_Operator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NODE_OT_Operator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]
*Result of calling the operator on all selected nodes in the shader editor*

[image]
*Result of calling the operator on all selected nodes in the compositor*

---

Demo on how to hide the *alpha sockets* of *Render Layer* and *Composite* node using the [console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html):

```
>>> rl_node = C.scene.node_tree.nodes.get('Render Layers')
>>> alpha_socket = rl_node.outputs.get("Alpha")
>>> alpha_socket.hide = True
>>>
>>> comp_node = C.scene.node_tree.nodes.get('Composite')
>>> alpha_socket = comp_node.inputs.get("Alpha")
>>> alpha_socket.hide = True
```

[image]
*Result of setting the state for each output or input socket*